# TouchEvents javascript jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, touch

I was making a scrollable items bar for mobile layout, but it seems to reset the calc randomly, not sure why.
If you inspect and set the responsive layout on chrome, for example, you'll see that sometimes the drag action to right makes items move to left and sometimes to right and vice versa.

It's supposed to take only horizontal drag/touch-scroll values (Y-Axis) and it works fine or bad randomly. I tried to console log the values but i can't find the pattern that causes this glitch.

Maybe a different way to make:

```
event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
```

tried one script from a post but still the same.

I tried with different calc for getting similar values of dragged distance but the result is the same. Can't figure out the reason, any advice/solution?

i'm leting a working snippet.

Thanks

```js
$(".flexbox-subcategory").on('touchstart', function(event) {
        // Getting the touchStart position.
        var touchStart = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
        var touchDistance = 0;
        var scrollDistance = 0;
        var actual = 0;

        // scroll bounds
        let min = 0;
        let max = -10;
        $('.flexbox-subcategory>.flexbox-subcategory-item').each( function(){ min += $(this).width(); });
        min = (min - 110) * -1;

        function touchMove(event) {
            // Dragged zone distance (width) calc:
            touchDistance = touchStart - event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
            // check actual left value
            actual = parseInt($(this).css('left').replace('px', ''));
            // set calc for new scroll value
            scrollDistance = actual + touchDistance;

            // Avoid scroll out of bounds
            if (scrollDistance > max) scrollDistance = max;
            if (scrollDistance < min) scrollDistance = min;
            // apply left value to emulate scroll
            $(this).css('left', scrollDistance);
        }

        $(this).on('touchmove', touchMove).one('touchend', function () {
            // turns off touchmove listener once
            $(this).off('touchmove', touchMove);
        });
    });
```

```css
.flex-wrap{
  width: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  
.flexbox-subcategory{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  }
  
 .flexbox-subcategory-item{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-wrap listingSubCategories">
    <div class="homepageListing flexbox-subcategory">
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="flexbox-subcategory-item">
          <a class="pretty-link" href="#">
              <div class="categoryBlock">
                  <div class="box-image">
                      image
                  </div>
                  <div class="box-title">
                      <h3>text</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I'll try to know if the swipe direction is from left or right and limit the calc using this value. It's a patch, not a solution but...